How to Derive the Exact Normal Force for a Wire Sliding Around a Tube Using the Capstan Equation?
I’ve been working on a problem that combines friction mechanics and abrasive wear, and I’ve hit a point where I could use some help. The issue revolves around calculating the exact normal force for a soft metal wire sliding around a hard cylindrical metal tube. While I know the Capstan equation provides a relationship between tension and friction:
Picture of Capstan Equation from Wikipedia
I’ve seen approximations that relate the normal force to the total tension, but I’d like to go further. Specifically, I’m trying to calculate the normal force by integrating along the angle of wrap,dθ, rather than assuming a simple proportionality. This approach should give a more rigorous understanding of the force distribution.
Here’s what I’ve considered so far:

The tension varies exponentially along the tube due to friction, as described by the Capstan equation.
The normal force at each differential segment of the angle, dθ, is related to the radial component of the tension.
I know the general idea is to integrate T(θ) over the wrap angle, ϕ, but I’m unsure how to rigorously include the mechanics of the system to ensure W (total normal force) is accurate and not conflated with total tension.

This calculation is critical because I want to apply the resulting normal force to the abrasive wear equation:
Archard equation from Wikipedia
Could anyone help guide me through the proper derivation of the exact normal force using the Capstan model? I’d also love to hear if there are alternative perspectives or improvements I might consider.
Thank you so much for your time — I truly appreciate any insights or corrections you can share as I am stuck!
